Как выполнить поиск с помощью регулярного выражения?
Можно ли найти через регулярное выражение все необычные словосочетания в тексте, такие как:
{color.RED}[text.test] - info:{color.END}.
Я хочу как-то заменить {color.RED} на [color=ffff00], а {color.END} на [/color].
Пример текста:
txt = "{color.RED}[проверка.значения] - нумерация: {color.END}профик натуры {color.BOARD}пример вывода{color.END} золотистый"
Вот это не трогать в тексте - {color.BOARD}пример вывода{color.END}.

нужно заменить именно Red словосочетания или любой цвет в его код превратить, например green в 00ff00? в первом случае достаточно обычной замены)

Было бы неплохо увидеть ваш код. И в целом вопрос размыт, нужны детали. Например, возможно ли вложение пар, маркирующих текст? Или допустима ли ситуация незакрытой разметки, как например с тегом <p> в HTML? Пример, где требуется детализация: "{color.RED}Hello {color.BOARD}world{color.END} out there!{color.END}" или тот же текст, но без "{color.END}" в конце, где его наличие как бы подразумевается по умолчанию.

Уффф, вот такое наколякал. Искомая строка:
\{color.RED\}([^\{]*)\{color.END\}

То, на что мы заменяем (replace):
[color=ffff00]$1[\color]

Главная идея заключается в том, чтобы выделить всё, что находится между двумя тэгами (т.е. между символами } и {), в отдельную группу. Для этого используем круглые скобки. Всё, что попадает в круглые скобки, можно в параметре replace вставлять как $1 - это первая группа. Таких групп можно много наделать, но в данной задаче одной хватит. Остальное дело обычного найти-замени: пишем что хотим видеть до и после нашей группы.
Внутри группы:
[^\{]*

Используем возможность регулярных выражений искать все символы, кроме [^любой символ]. Нам нужно искать до первого попавшегося символа фигурная скобка, поэтому и указываем её как единственную, кого не хотим видеть в нашей группе.
